# Problem with keyframes

Tags: animation

So first I added keyframes for the robot bobbing up and down and then added a rotation to her body and this is the result: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2lLgtj1HkQ&feature=youtu.be

I want her body to be rotated throughout the whole animation like that [image]

I'm also planning on making her wave her hand

I really cant describe the problem well, just watch the video and you'll understand.

Also do you have any recommendations for free screenrecorder? :D

Comment: your video doesn't work

Comment: The screencapture was too long to upload as a gif, so I uploaded it on youtube. Or is there a problem with the youtube video?

Comment: Oh, I see the problem, I put it as private instead of unlisted.it should work now

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, could you please describe more accurately? Maybe what you need is a root bone to which your first spline bone will be parented, but I'm not sure as your problem is not clear to me

Comment: This will be hard. The motion of her rotating her body only starts after the secong keyframe and after the 3rd keyframe it just resets to default position. So basically the problem is that the motion of her bobbing up and down interupts the rotation of the body

Comment: so as I said maybe you should add a root bone so that the bobbing move will be completely independent from the rotation of the whole body. You just have to add a big bone at the bottom and make it the parent of the spline basis. You could also move the armature in Object mode, but the best is always to create a root bone so that the armature remains not animated.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. Mind posting that as an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you need to do is create a root bone that will allow you to move your robot up and down while its spine will rotate:

- In *Edit* mode, create a root bone. Make it the parent of the spine basis (and also of all the IK controllers, pole targets, etc...).
- In the *Properties* panel > *Bone* > disable the *Deform* option so that this kind of bone (like IK controllers, pole targets...) won't have any influence on the mesh.
- Now you can independently rotate the spine basis and move the root up and down.

Another way could be to move the armature in *Object* mode, but the best, if your robot stay rather still on the scene, is to create a root bone so that the armature (as an object) remains not animated.

But when you'll make your robot move along a path, most of the time you'll use this second option, though.

[image]